# C# Easiest way to parse simple XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML string that I need in the most easy and efficient way to convert into a `List<string>` or `string[]` having only the groupuid values.

```
   <root>
       <group groupuid="5dc9eb2e-f38f-4b4d-99f2-d756ab849249" />
       <group groupuid="e2d1106d-e6e5-4eb4-8482-96f7c45e05e9" />
       <group groupuid="319f211d-a366-489f-859f-4dbf9c388353" />
    </root>
```

I know there are libraries like XMLDoc where you can navigate to the nodes and then attributes etc, but maybe there is an easiest way to do it.

Any recommendation?

Comment: how about linq to xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Linq To Xml, by using [**XDocument**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netcore-3.1),

```
string xml = @"<root>
               <group groupuid='5dc9eb2e-f38f-4b4d-99f2-d756ab849249' />
               <group groupuid='e2d1106d-e6e5-4eb4-8482-96f7c45e05e9' />
               <group groupuid='319f211d-a366-489f-859f-4dbf9c388353' />
            </root>";

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//Or if you have a file path
//XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);

List<string> result = xDocument.Descendants("group")
    .Select(x => x.Attribute("groupuid").Value)
    .ToList();
```

Namespace to add:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Class to deserialize the XML.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "group")]
    public List<Group> Group { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "group")]
public class Group
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "groupuid")]
    public string Groupuid { get; set; }
}
```

and in main, you can use the following to deserialize the XML,

```
Root obj;
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    obj = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

obj.Group.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Groupuid));

// Prints
5dc9eb2e-f38f-4b4d-99f2-d756ab849249
e2d1106d-e6e5-4eb4-8482-96f7c45e05e9
319f211d-a366-489f-859f-4dbf9c388353
```

Comment: I think creating separate classes to deserialize to is overkill compared with the LINQ to XML approach as per Sajid's answer.

Comment: I always prefer using concrete classes but for simplicity sake, you can use Linq and names you need to look up.